# Filter in UITableVewController of multiple object

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

Sorry to ask this but I am very new on this. Hi i have an `NSMutableArray` that contains data like below:

```
{
Code = MCP3441G;
"Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body MH";
"Needle Dimension" = "31 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 7440;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 5474;
Size = "2/0";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL monofilament 70 CM Violet";
nid = 86;
},
{
Code = NW1641;
"Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body";
"Needle Dimension" = "30 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 4800;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 3510;
Size = "2/0 Only";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
nid = 86;
},
{
Code = NW1642;
"Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body";
"Needle Dimension" = "30 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 4800;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 3510;
Size = "1/0";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
nid = 86;
},
{
Code = NW1648;
"Needle Description" = "3/8 Circle Round Body";
"Needle Dimension" = "16 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 3600;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 2687;
Size = "4/0";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 cm";
nid = 86;
},
```

Now i want to filter the object based on the search. For example if i type **`NW1648`** So last object should be only visible.  Means i section:

```
{
Code = NW1648;
"Needle Description" = "3/8 Circle Round Body";
"Needle Dimension" = "16 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 3600;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 2687;
Size = "4/0";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 cm";
nid = 86;
},
```

Below is the method that i am using to filter the data :

```
#pragma Search Method
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",searchText];
    searchedData = [self->datas filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]] ];
    return YES;
}
```

**Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.**

**Updated #1:**

```
I am storing below data in `NSMutableDictionary` like below:



  {
Code = NW1648;
"Needle Description" = "3/8 Circle Round Body";
"Needle Dimension" = "16 MM";
"No. of foils per box" = 12;
"Per box maximum retail price" = 3600;
"Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 2687;
Size = "4/0";
"Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 cm";
nid = 86;
},

 NSMutableDictionary *resultantDataObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_ID] forKey:SKU_CODE];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_NEEDLE_DESC] forKey:NEEDLE_DESCRIPTION];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_NEEDLE_DIMENSION] forKey:NEEDLE_DIMENSION];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_SUTURE] forKey:SUTURE_TYPE];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_SIZE] forKey:SIZE];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_FOILS] forKey:FOILS_PER_BOXEX];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_RETAILS_HOSPITAL] forKey:HOSPITAL_PRICE];
    [resultantDataObject setObject:[val valueForKey:CODE_MAX_RETAIL] forKey:MAXIMUM_RETAILS];
```

Here i am adding this `NSMutableDictionary` in `NSMutableArray`

```
[data addObject:resultantDataObject];
```

**Updated #2:** I have object now i want to searched based on what he types and if he i.e.
He types `34 Mono` so i want to search this in all keys and 34 could be in any key and then again search with mono in all keys and filter the value which has both keywords.

Comment: **self->datas** this is your **array** or **dictionary**, if it is dictionary it is easy to filter

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Its a `MutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary'

Comment: k whats your `NSMUtableDictionary` Name, bz u find/search  the code only na, it is easy to fetch the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *filteredArr = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Code == %@)", searchText]];
NSLog(@"%@",filteredArr);
```

Hope this helps.. :)

If you want to add more key do this:

```
NSArray *filteredArr = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Code == %@) AND (Needle Description == %@) AND (Needle Dimension == %@)", searchText,needleDescription, needleDimentsion]];
```

Comment: i want filter in all the fields

Comment: @User3154663 > Then add those in the predicate. :)